# SQL Server - Problems with linked server

Tags: sql-server

It's kind of a abstract question buy I am new to SQL Server and don't know how to correctly formulate the question.

We had several problems with getting data from linked server and running procedures on it.
There was an error once: "Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SERVERNAME".

I've read that firewall can block connection. Did anyone experienced smth like this? How did you solved it?

Also I seen that there could be a problem with writing to "Temp" folder. Did anyone experienced the situation when disk could be full and linked server didn't worked because of this?

Maybe there could be any other cause?

Comment: The problem is that these errors are sporadic and happen from time to time.

Comment: Your password wouldn't happen to also be "IForgotMyPasswordAgain3" would it?

Comment: @roryap Nope. But you could try; =)